# spinctrl that scales up and down by increments/decrements of 10

Tags: wxpython

So I am developing a GUI in wxPython and I have seen from the documentation that there isn't an option for the `Spin Control` to increase or decrease by a value greater than 1.

I want one that increases or decreases by 10.

How do I implement this? `NumCtrl` and `IntCtrl` also don't seem to have this option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for a control that can increment and decrement by a value you have chosen, say 10 for my case, I discovered just now that you can use the 'FloatSpin' control. It is in the "agw" library. Here is a link to the documentation for it:

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.floatspin.html

It did what I wanted it to do.